# Why is my mp3/ogg unseekable when served from Drupal 7 private files when it is seekable from public files

Tags: php, drupal-7, html5-audio

I wrote my own JavaScript HTML5 audio player that works great when the files are sourced form Drupal 7 public files, but cannot be seeked when served from Drupal 7 private files. I am logged in so why would this occur?

I wasted a good deal of time debugging and rewriting my code, only to discover that it was the public/vs private that was causing errors, I eventually figured it out by using the seekable object which was returning no seekable timelines for private src but working fine for public.

I have searched for this issue, and find many unrelated but similar issues, but none that explain this behavior.

Comment: I'm going to guess they route the private files though a PHP script which does not support the appropriate headers such as Range.

Comment: Wow - that was it exactly, I bit more googling with keywords from your comment and: "....The byterange filter is built-in to Apache's HTTP handling; I'm not even sure it can be easily turned off. However, when using private files the data is transferred by Drupal's file_download() function, which doesn't support range requests, and mod_php sends the entire document if it's greater than 8000 bytes." from http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/iphone-video-streaming-drupals-file-system

Comment: How can I give you credit, I think you need to provide and answer vs a comment?

Comment: Sure, I posted an answer. Just wanted to be sure this was the problem.

Comment: Thanks, by the way behaviour is the way us Canucks spell it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal private files, like most authenticated PHP download scripts, route the file request through a PHP script. These scripts (almost) never support the appropriate headers, such as the `Range` header, required to do things like resume download or requests parts of the file as seeking does.

Usually the best solution to these problems is to not use a PHP script to output the file, as it add's unnecessary load to the server. Alternative solutions for authenticated downloads include `X-Sendfile` (if available or it can be installed), a temporary randomly-named symbolic link in a public directory, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue using Private Files for Audiofield and jPlayer on Drupal 7, using the [Resumable Downloa](https://www.drupal.org/project/resumable_download)d module and this [patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/2408531)